# ¿Cómo detectar la accion click derecho del ratón + eliminar en internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Quiero detectar cuando el usuario cambia el contenido del campo de texto. Cuando lo hace por teclado es fácil, pero con el menú contextual, al pulsar el botón derecho del ratón vienen los problemas.

Las acciones de pegar/copiar/cortar están definidas y se les puede asignar una función, como por ejemplo.

```
object.onpaste = object.oncut = object.oncopy = function (){
    alert("estas cambiando el contenido"};
}
```

Pero a la acción click derecho + eliminar (internet explorer) no hay forma de detectarla.

¿Cómo detectar la accion "click derecho del ratón + eliminar" en internet explorer?

En la página stackoverflow inglesa dan alguna solución pero consiste en ejecutar una función por intervalos con "setInterval", y que esta función compruebe el tamaño del texto cada X milisegundos. 
Podría ser una solución pero no sé cómo puede afectar al rendimiento, porque además habría que aplicarla en varios campos dentro de una misma pantalla.

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con la funcion de Eliminar. Puedes explicar lo que hace?  es como un cortar pero de todo el input?

Comment: Quieres que solo capture cuando das `Botón derecho + eliminar` o también cuando utilizas `backspace` ?

Comment: @lois6b en Internet Explorer al dar click derecho con el ratón en el menú aparece la opción Eliminar a diferencia de otros navegadores que no lo tienen (si no es que todos los demás no lo tienen).

Comment: @lixus si, de eso me he enterado. lo que quiero saber es qué hace. El autor deberia explicarlo para quien (como yo) no lo conozca.

Comment: @lois6b hace lo mismo que la tecla backspace

Comment: @lixus pero de todo el input a la vez? o sea, lo vacia por completo ?

Comment: @lois6b no, va caracter por caracter.

Comment: como se le quita el puesto en espera??

Comment: Según tengo entendido elimina el contenido seleccionado del input. Una posible solución puede ser escuchar al evento `input` y comprobar si el tamaño del contenido del input decrece. Pero, claro, tendrías que descartar otras posibles combinaciones de teclas que también eliminan contenido como `backspace, ctrl +X, Supr, Del, ...`

Comment: oye amigo si lo que quieres es detectar el evento click derecho y izquierdo de tu mause puedes ir a este link esta en ingles pero es entendible saludos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725963/4717133

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Quiero detectar cuando el usuario cambia el contenido del campo de texto. Cuando lo hace por teclado es fácil, pero con el menú contextual al pulsar el botón derecho del ratón vienen los problemas. Las acciones de pegar/copiar/cortar están definidas y se les puede asignar una función como he puesto en el ejemplo. Pero a la acción click derecho + eliminar (internet explorer) no hay forma de detectarla. He visto que se puede hacer definiendo una función que salte por intervalos y compruebe el tamaño (con el setInterval).

Comment: Prueba con el change de jquery

Comment: @GDP se reabrió la pregunta en caso de que quieras responder

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo finalmente lo he hecho como dijiste, escuchando el evento input! Muchas gracias! Si quieres ponerlo como respuesta...

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo
Esta ha sido la solucion: 
$('#id_objeto').bind("input", function (event){//manejarEvento});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente la solución ha sido controlar el evento input:

```
$('#id_objeto').bind("input", function (event){//manejarEvento});
```

Con esto he conseguido detectar cuando el usuario elimina texto del campo mediante el menú contextual del ratón (click derecho + eliminar).

Gracias al usuario @JoseHermosillaRodrigo por el consejo!

Answer (score 1):

Intenta quitando el menú

```js
function nomenu(){
return false;
}
document.getElementById("sinmenu").oncontextmenu = nomenu;
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Sin Menu" id="sinmenu">
  <input type="text" value="Con Menu" id="conmenu">
```

Comment: Gracias lo voy a intentar. Aunque no sé si me valdrá la solución de cara al cliente. Otra solución sería quitar la opción "eliminar" del menú conceptual del explorer, pero no sé si es posible.

Comment: No es posible modificar el menú, otra solucion aunque no es fácil y no funcionara en todos los navegadores sería que tu crearas un menú personalizado (con elementos html) y emularas los eventos de copiar y pegar

Comment: Me lo temía. La solución de crear un menú personalizado quizás me valga. Creo que usaré una de las dos, o una función con SetInterval o crear un propio menú personalizado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda